# System76 laptops battery life

Tags: laptop, battery

I have been impressed by the System76 laptops as they are designed for and ship with Ubuntu.  I strongly feel the most important feature of a portable computer is that it is actually portable, i.e. has a long battery life.  I could not find battery life estimates on their webpage.  If you have used one of these computers with Ubuntu, how long was it able to run on battery power?

I realize this varies, particularly when turning on an Nvidia card but what has been your experience?

Please feel free to redirect me if this question would be more appropriate somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not included as it varies with what spec you choose - e.g. looking at the specs of [this model](https://system76.com/laptops/gazelle) off of their front page, the fact you can have a i5 or i7 CPU, as well as [choose what display, RAM, wifi etc](https://system76.com/cart/configure/gazp9) it has will affect battery life - I will note that I think 62.16 Wh is very good compared to (lower-power) laptops I have had, but as this is off the front page is may be more expensive than most anyway.

What I would recommend doing is either search for reviews (doing this for most purchases helps anyway) - e.g. [this one](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/the-system76-gazelle-professional-just-how-good-is-it-review) says:

> I’ve not done extensive testing of the battery life, but most of the
>   time Ubuntu suggests two hours from a full charge, and that seems to
>   be true. While it definitely isn’t something you’d completely rely on
>   while on the go, it’s understandable considering all this great
>   hardware this laptop houses. If you’re doing something chilled like
>   casual tweeting and IM’ing, then the laptop should be able to last
>   three full hours.

Or try contacting System76 via their [support](https://system76.com/support) services and asking them directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  These were my thoughts before asking here.  I did not find any recent reviews (2014-2015) so I thought I would ask here in hopes of receiving specific comments from users.

Comment: Here is the response I got from emailing System76:  HI Steven,
Thank you for your interest in our products! All the laptops are going to get 3.5-4 hours depending on usage. We are releasing a new 14" laptop in early April that has up to 9 hours battery life with an Intel i3 CPU and will start at $599.